# Tkinter, curselection()[0], IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite

I am connecting frontend to backend of a database application using Tkinter and sqlite3.

Need help finding potential reasons that resulted in this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Peng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "frontend.py", line 9, in get_selected_row
    index=list1.curselection()[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

But `list1.curselection()[0]` is just the `id`, why is it out of range?

Any help on finding where went wrong will be greatly appreciated!!!

My code:

frontend.py:

```
from tkinter import *
import backend
window=Tk()

list1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',get_selected_row)

def update_command():
    backend.update(selected_tuple[0],title_text.get()，author_text.get(),year_text.get(),isbn_text.get())

def get_selected_row(event):
    global selected_tuple
    index=list1.curselection()[0]
    selected_tuple=list1.get(index)
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e1.insert(END,selected_tuple[1])
    e2.delete(0,END)
    e2.insert(END,selected_tuple[2])
    e3.delete(0,END)
    e3.insert(END,selected_tuple[3])
    e4.delete(0,END)
    e4.insert(END,selected_tuple[4])
```

backend.py:

```
import sqlite3

def update(id,title,author,year,isbn):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE book SET title=?,author=?,year=?,isbn=? WHERE id=?",(title,author,year,isbn,id))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: That means you called `curselection` when there was nothing selected.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `list1.curselection()` is returning what you're assuming it's returning?

Comment: Right, it seems the problem is that it is called when nothing is selected. However, the same error message pops up when I try to create an exe file. So, what can I do to avoid this? Thanks guys, really appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you simply check for whether anything is selected before trying to use the selection?

Comment: Right! Thank you so much. Hahah, I'm so new at this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is being triggered when there is nothing selected. The easiest fix is to simply check if the tuple is empty:

```
def get_selected_row(event):
    global selected_tuple
    index=list1.curselection()
    if index: # if the tuple is not empty
        selected_tuple=list1.get(index[0])
        e1.delete(0,END)
        e1.insert(END,selected_tuple[1])
        e2.delete(0,END)
        e2.insert(END,selected_tuple[2])
        e3.delete(0,END)
        e3.insert(END,selected_tuple[3])
        e4.delete(0,END)
        e4.insert(END,selected_tuple[4])
```

A more proper fix is to find out when it's being triggered like that and prevent it.

Answer (score 3):

it happens when you click into the list1 while it is empty
this is the line that triggers it

```
list1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',get_selected_row)
```

the solution mentioned above is suitable since you don't seem to have any other code manipulating this event
however, i would word the solution a bit differently, to be consistent with your code naming conventions:

```
def get_selected_row(event):
    global selected_tuple
    if list1.curselection():
        index=list1.curselection()[0]
        selected_tuple=list1.get(index)
        e1.delete(0,END)
        e1.insert(END,selected_tuple[1])
        e2.delete(0,END)
        e2.insert(END,selected_tuple[2])
        e3.delete(0,END)
        e3.insert(END,selected_tuple[3])
        e4.delete(0,END)
        e4.insert(END,selected_tuple[4])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the listbox is empty, then list1.curselection()will be an empty list with no items. Trying to access the first item of that list with [0] in line 3 will throw an error since there is no first item in the list.

```
def get_selected_row(event):
    try:
        global selected_tuple
        index=list1.curselection()
        selected_tuple=list1.get(index[0])
        e1.delete(0,END)
        e1.insert(END,selected_tuple[1])
        e2.delete(0,END)
        e2.insert(END,selected_tuple[2])
        e3.delete(0,END)
        e3.insert(END,selected_tuple[3])
        e4.delete(0,END)
        e4.insert(END,selected_tuple[4])
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

When the get_selected_row function is called, Python will try to execute the indentedblock under try. If there is an IndexErrornone of the lines under try will be executed. Instead the line under except will be executed which is pass. Thepass stetementmeans do nothing. So the function will do nothing when there's an empty listbox.